# Waiting For Connection (netbeans-xdebug) using NetBeans

Tags: netbeans, xdebug

I have tried everything I can to get xdebug running with NetBeans. I have tried every suggestion on every forum I could find, but none have helped. No matter what I do, I ALWAYS get the dreaded "Waiting For Connection (netbeans-xdeubg)" and nothing happens.

Win 10. Apache running locally. Virus and Firewall have both been disabled. Listening on 9001 (I also tried 9000, no change).

relevant php.ini:

```
[XDebug]
zend_extension = php_xdebug-2.5.4-5.6-vc11.dll
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
xdebug.remote_host=127.0.0.1
xdebug.remote_port=9001
xdebug.remote_autostart=1
xdebug.remote_connect_back=1
xdebug.remote_mode=req
xdebug.idekey="netbeans-xdebug"

xdebug.profiler_append = 0
xdebug.profiler_enable = 1
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger = 0
xdebug.profiler_output_dir = "c:\temp"
;xdebug.profiler_output_name = "cachegrind.out.%t-%s"
xdebug.remote_log="c:\temp\xdebug.txt"
xdebug.trace_output_dir = "c:\temp"
; 3600 (1 hour), 36000 = 10h
xdebug.remote_cookie_expire_time = 36000
xdebug.var_display_max_data = 2048
```

Net Beans project config:

```
Debugger Proxy: 127.0.0.1, Port 9001
```

Net Beans php debugging (Tools->Options->PHP->Debugging):

```
Debugger Port: 9001
Session ID: netbeans-xdebug
Max Data Length: 2048
```

[EDIT: @lazyone]
After NetBeans Launch and manually opening browser tab:

C:\WINDOWS\system32>netstat -o -n -a -b (excluded any non-9001 results):

```
  TCP    0.0.0.0:9001           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
 [netbeans64.exe]
  TCP    127.0.0.1:9001         127.0.0.1:63119        ESTABLISHED
 [netbeans64.exe]
  TCP    127.0.0.1:9001         127.0.0.1:63123        ESTABLISHED
 [netbeans64.exe]
  TCP    127.0.0.1:63119        127.0.0.1:9001         ESTABLISHED
 [netbeans64.exe]
  TCP    127.0.0.1:63123        127.0.0.1:9001         ESTABLISHED
 [httpd.exe]
  TCP    [::]:9001              [::]:0                 LISTENING
 [netbeans64.exe]
```

When I run the project, it sits and waits; browser does not react. When I kill debugging session, the browser immediately pulls up a tab with the proper url (http://local.ct.com/info.php?XDEBUG_SESSION_START=netbeans-xdebug). I have tried manually starting that URL when the IDE is waiting, but nothing changes.

Note that if I examine the remote log when I start the debugging from NetBeans (waiting...) then stop it, I get the following in the log:

```
Log opened at 2017-10-11 18:18:26
I: Checking remote connect back address.
I: Checking header 'HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'.
I: Checking header 'REMOTE_ADDR'.
I: Remote address found, connecting to 127.0.0.1:9001.
E: Time-out connecting to client. :-(
Log closed at 2017-10-11 18:18:26
```

If instead I start debugging in Netbeans (waiting...), then manually open the tab (still waiting...), then stop it, I get the following in the log:

```
Log opened at 2017-10-11 18:21:29
I: Checking remote connect back address.
I: Checking header 'HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'.
I: Checking header 'REMOTE_ADDR'.
I: Remote address found, connecting to 127.0.0.1:9001.
I: Connected to client. :-)
-> <init xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="http://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" fileuri="file:///C:/userdata/CMP/ct/cmp/ct/htdocs/info.php" language="PHP" xdebug:language_version="5.6.1-dev" protocol_version="1.0" appid="13596" idekey="netbeans-xdebug"><engine version="2.5.4"><![CDATA[Xdebug]]></engine><author><![CDATA[Derick Rethans]]></author><url><![CDATA[http://xdebug.org]]></url><copyright><![CDATA[Copyright (c) 2002-2017 by Derick Rethans]]></copyright></init>

-> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="http://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" status="stopping" reason="ok"></response>

Log closed at 2017-10-11 18:21:34

Log opened at 2017-10-11 18:21:34
I: Checking remote connect back address.
I: Checking header 'HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'.
I: Checking header 'REMOTE_ADDR'.
I: Remote address found, connecting to 127.0.0.1:9001.
E: Time-out connecting to client. :-(
Log closed at 2017-10-11 18:21:34
```

I have been working on this a ridiculously long time. Any help would be GREATLY appreciated!

Comment: have you checked xdebug loaded correctly in phpinfo() ? Is your xdebug match your php version ?

Comment: Side note: `netstat -o -n -a | findstr :9001` -- can you add `-b` parameter and see what process is actually listening that port? By your description (actions taken and their response in xdebug log) it should be NetBeans .. but it does not respond to incoming xdebug request as it should (even when it responds .. it's way too short). That single time when it responded looks like it's not an IDE responding but some php-pfm ...

Comment: This one is a bit off-topic ... but do you think you can try another editor/IDE to see how debug will work there? I'm not talking about permanent transition .. more of "check if it will work there". From my side I may suggest PhpStorm (https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Debugging+with+PhpStorm)

Comment: @tan - should have added that. Yes - xdebug is in phpinfo (v2.5.4). It matches the .dll ver specified in the php.ini file. That .dll was determiined here (https://xdebug.org/wizard.php). I also added xdebug calls to my info.php file and they are being called successfully.

Comment: @LazyOne - see edits above (thank you)

Comment: @LazyOne - I have tried with Notepad++ (admittedly, their support is aging) to no avail. If I can't get NetBeans working, I'll switch back to Eclipse and try.

Comment: Any chance of collecting php debug related logs from NetBeans side (if it supports it)? Maybe it can tell something (e.g. path mappings etc). but so far (based on the log) it just connects and disconnects straight away (normally) without any interaction (e.g. checking for some variables etc). maybe the file you are trying to edit is outside of the project ... or you have not setup any breakpoints etc. Hard to say. But I may suggest this: brand new project, single file with most simple code (`$a = 5; $b = 3; $c = $a +$b;`) to see if it works. No symbolic links anywhere.

Comment: Other than that -- try simplifying xdebug config and only leave most important ones: `zend_extension = php_xdebug-2.5.4-5.6-vc11.dll` (try with full path just in case), `xdebug.remote_enable=1` , `xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp`, `xdebug.remote_host=127.0.0.1`, `xdebug.remote_port=9001`, `xdebug.remote_mode=req`, `xdebug.idekey="netbeans-xdebug"` May also leave `xdebug.remote_autostart=1` and `xdebug.remote_log="c:\temp\xdebug.txt"`. **P.S.** Still recommend to check PhpStorm (trial is fully functional) -- maybe it will perform better .. or be able to tell a bit more about reasons behind.

Comment: @LazyOne - the only NetBeans log I could find had nothing of use in it, unfortunately. I like your suggestion of going back to a super simple project; I'll give that a shot.

Comment: @LazyOne - using the exact same xdebug configuration I was able to get it working in Eclipse without much trouble. I'm thinking it must be either a NetBeans config issue or a NetBeans bug.